# Partial derivatives in a skew coordinate system

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, coordinate-systems

I am a math hobbyist. I'm learning partial derivatives. All the examples I've come across deal with orthogonal coordinates. I am wondering what, if any, adjustments need to be made when taking partial derivatives in skew coordinates. When I've looked this question up on the web, the explanations were beyond me (e.g spoke of covariant and contravariant bases).

Let's say you have a simple function: $f(x,y) = 2x + 3y$. In an orthonormal coordinate system, the partial derivatives would be easy: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 3$, and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 2$. This depends on ones ability to consider $2x$ to be a constant when taking the partial with respect to $x$, and similarly to consider $3y$ to be constant when taking the partial with respect to $y$. But this wouldn't be the case in a skew coordinate system.

Say you have a two-dimensional coordinate system where the angle between the two axes is an acute angle $\phi$. (For example, the $y$-axis is rotated clockwise by $\frac{\pi}{2} - \phi$.) Then, when you move a distance, $h$, in the $x$ direction, you also move cos($\phi$) $\times $ $h$ in the $y$ direction. I've tried to work out what happens to partial derivatives as a result of this non-orthogonality between axes.

The formulation for the partial derivative with respect to $y$ in an orthonormal coordinate system is:

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h,y) - f(x,y)}{h}.$$

For the skew system I described above, since moving $h$ in the $x$ direction moves h cos($\phi$) $\times $ $h$ in the $y$ direction would this have to become:

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h,y+\cos(\phi) \times h) - f(x,y)}{h} ?$$

For $f(x,y) = 2x + 3y$, would $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 2 + 3\cos(\phi)?$

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but it seems like you may have independently invented the concept of the "directional derivative". ([English Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative), [Paul's Online Notes page](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/directionalderiv.aspx), [openstax page](https://openstax.org/books/calculus-volume-3/pages/4-6-directional-derivatives-and-the-gradient))

Comment: $\,f(x,y)\,$ denotes a function of two variables. There is no mention here of coordinate systems. The two variables are just two real numbers. Introducing coordinates is another matter.

Comment: Thanks @somos. Does one need to add a coordinate system to take the partial derivatives?

Comment: The answer is no. Once you define a function of several variables, then you can define and evaluate partial derivatives with respect to any one of the variables. Again, no coordinate systems are involved here.

Comment: Thanks again, @Somos. For some reason, possibly to make things more geometrically intuitive, many of the examples I've come across make reference to coordinate systems when explaining partial derivatives. For example, they will talk about moving parallel to the $y$-axis when taking the partial derivative wrt $x$, thus keeping $x$ constant (with cartesian coordinates).

Comment: You are certainly correct that many expositions implicitly or explicitly assume a Cartesian coordinate system in order to be more intuitive, it can be misleading if that leads to the assumption that a coordinate system is required to evaluate partial derivates. There are examples in thermodynamics with interrelated variables that make partial derivates wrt those thermodynamic variables hard to understand due to implicit assumptions about the relations between variables.